# Why is the Matlab parfor scheduler leaving workers idle?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a fairly long-running `parfor` loop (let's say 100,000 iterations where each iterations takes about a minute) that I'm running with 36 cores. I've noticed that near the end of the job, a large number of the cores go idle while a few finish what I think has to be multiple iterations per worker. This leads to a lot of wasted computing time waiting for one worker to finish several jobs while the others are sitting idle.

The following script shows the issue (using the File Exchange utility `Par.m`):

```
% Set up parallel pool
nLoop = 480;
p1 = gcp;

% Run a loop 
pclock = Par(nLoop);
parfor iLoop = 1:nLoop
  Par.tic;
  pause(0.1);
  pclock(iLoop) = Par.toc;  
end
stop(pclock);
plot(pclock);

% Process the timing info: 
runs = [[pclock.Worker]' [pclock.ItStart]' [pclock.ItStop]'];
nRuns = arrayfun(@(x) sum(runs(:,1) == x), 1:max(runs));
starts = nan(max(nRuns), p1.NumWorkers);
ends = nan(max(nRuns), p1.NumWorkers);
for iS = 1:p1.NumWorkers
  starts(1:nRuns(iS), iS) = sort(runs(runs(:, 1) == iS, 2));
  ends(1:nRuns(iS), iS) = sort(runs(runs(:, 1) == iS, 3));
end

firstWorkerStops = min(max(ends));
badRuns = starts > firstWorkerStops;
nBadRuns = sum(sum(badRuns)) - (p1.NumWorkers-1);

fprintf('At least %d (%3.1f%%) iterations run inefficiently.\n', ...
  nBadRuns, nBadRuns/nLoop * 100);
```

The way I'm looking at it, every worker should be busy until the queue is empty, after which all workers sit idle. But here it looks like that's not happening - with 480 iterations, I'm getting between 6-20 iterations that start on a worker after a different worker has been sitting idle *for a full cycle*. This number appears to scale linearly with the number of loop iterations coming in near 2% of the total. With limited testing this appears to be consistent across Matlab 2016b and 2014b.

Is there any reason that this is the expected behavior or is this simply a poorly written scheduler in the `parfor` implementation? If so, how can I structure this so I'm not sitting around with idle workers so long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parfor` scheduler attempts to load-balance for loops where the iterations do not take a uniform amount of time. Unfortunately, as you observe, this can lead to workers becoming idle at the end of the loop. With `parfor`, you don't have control over the division of work; but you could use `parfeval` to divide your work up into even chunks - that might give you better utilisation. Or, you could even use `spmd` in conjunction with a [`for-drange`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/using-a-for-loop-over-a-distributed-range-for-drange.html) loop.

Comment: How would you do the explicit scheduling with `spmd`? I think I wrote up an example but it seems to suffer the same problem as `parfor`.

Comment: The `for-drange` construct simply divides up the loop iterations into equally-sized chunks, that's what I meant. This is fine if each iteration takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this explains what you are observing.

> If there are more iterations than workers, some workers perform more than one loop iteration; in this case, a worker might receive multiple iterations at once to reduce communication time. (From "[When to Use parfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/introduction-to-parfor.html)")

Towards the end of a loop, a two workers may finish their iterations at around the same time. If there is only one group of iterations left to be assigned, then one worker will get them all, and the other will remain idle. It sounds like it is expected behavior, and it is probably because the underlying implementation tries to reduce the communication cost associated with a worker pool. I've looked around the web and the Matlab settings and it doesn't seem like there is a way to adjust the communication strategy.